# Line-height элемента относительно родительского элемента в меню

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Нужно получить высоту Родительского элемента в меню и установить данное значение в line-height кнопки, что бы выровнять стрелку по центу.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#cssmenu li.has-sub >span').on('click', function() {
    $(this).removeAttr('href');
    var element = $(this).parent('li');
    if (element.hasClass('open')) {
      element.removeClass('open');
      element.find('li').removeClass('open');
      element.find('ul').hide();
    } else {
      element.addClass('open');
      element.children('ul').show();
      element.siblings('li').children('ul').hide();
      element.siblings('li').removeClass('open');
      element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('open');
      element.siblings('li').find('ul').hide();
    }
  });

  $('.accordion-btn').each(function() {
    var parentItem = $('#accordion-btn').closest('li'),
      lineheight = $('> a', parentItem).innerHeight();
    $('#accordion-btn').css({
      'line-height': lineheight + 'px',
      'height': lineheight
    });
  })
});
```

```css
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#cssmenu {
  width: 200px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#cssmenu ul ul {
  display: none;
}

.align-right {
  float: right;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li>a {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  border-left: 1px solid #1682ba;
  border-right: 1px solid #1682ba;
  border-top: 1px solid #1682ba;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  background: #36aae7;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  background: linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
}

#cssmenu>ul>li>a:hover,
#cssmenu>ul>li.active>a,
#cssmenu>ul>li.open>a {
  color: #eeeeee;
  background: #1fa0e4;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
  background: linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
}

#cssmenu>ul>li.open>a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1682ba;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li:last-child>a,
#cssmenu>ul>li.last>a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1682ba;
}

.holder {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.holder::after,
.holder::before {}

.holder::after {
  top: 17px;
  border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
  border-left: 2px solid #ffffff;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li>a:hover>span::after,
#cssmenu>ul>li.active>a>span::after,
#cssmenu>ul>li.open>a>span::after {
  border-color: #eeeeee;
}

.holder::before {
  top: 18px;
  border-top: 2px solid;
  border-left: 2px solid;
  border-top-color: inherit;
  border-left-color: inherit;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #32373e;
  border-left: 1px solid #32373e;
  border-right: 1px solid #32373e;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #eeeeee;
  background: #49505a;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

#cssmenu ul ul li:hover>a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.open>a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.active>a {
  background: #424852;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li:first-child>a {
  box-shadow: none;
}

#cssmenu ul ul ul li:first-child>a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

#cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li>ul>li:last-child>a,
#cssmenu>ul>li>ul>li.last>a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li>ul>li.open:last-child>a,
#cssmenu>ul>li>ul>li.last.open>a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #32373e;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li>ul>li.open:last-child>ul>li:last-child>a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub>a::after {}

#cssmenu ul ul li.active>a::after,
#cssmenu ul ul li.open>a::after,
#cssmenu ul ul li>a:hover::after {
  border-color: #ffffff;
}

.accordion-btn-wrap {
  width: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: 99999;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.accordion-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.has-sub {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/js/all.js"></script>
<div id='cssmenu'>
  <ul>
    <li><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li class='active has-sub'>
      <a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
      <span class="accordion-btn-wrap"><!-- Кнопка-->
                   <span class="accordion-btn">
                      <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                   </span>
      </span>
      <!-- Конец кнопки-->
      <ul>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a>
          <span class="accordion-btn-wrap">
                      <span class="accordion-btn">
                         <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                      </span>
          </span>
          <ul>
            <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
            <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
            <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
    <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Вроде простая задача, нужно сделать что то вроде цикла, где есть класс has-sub, у того элемента брать высоту и задать ее элементу, пытался написать что то похожее но не работает

Нарисовал схему небольшую

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В css есть значение `inherit` - берет значение у родительского элемента. Попробуйте, это лучше, чем js. И еще, у вас не правильные селекторы `#accordion-btn` - ищет элемент с `id="accordion-btn"`.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko это свойство работает если только высота блока заранее известно вроде как , в моем случае высота может динамический изменяться в зависимости от длинны текста, по этому тут только через js(. С селекторами и правда косяк , спасибо

Comment: С чего вы это взяли? Если у родителя будет меняться значение `line-height` то и у дочернего элемента с `line-height:inherit`  тоже будет меняться.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko я как то попытался использовать это свойство , но никак не работает, не подскажите как можно его использовать ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделай проще и без скриптов, для стрелки добавь следующие стили:

```
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

ну и не забудь допилить все необходимые вендорные префиксы для `transform: translateY`

**CSS3** уже давно поддерживается всеми браузерами, не понимаю почему многие чураются их использовать, 2018 год на дворе как никак

Comment: Тут ваше решение не совсем подходит, меню же раскрывающееся, таким образом стрелка выравнивается по середине, но по нажатию элемент li становится шире и стрелка опять смещается

Comment: ну да, вообще это вечная проблема с вертикальным выравниванием...  но ведь можно сделать еще один уровень вложенности, положить ссылку и стрелку ещё в один блок, выравнивать стрелку внутри этого блока, а раскрывающееся меню будет под этим блоком

Comment: Если ответ вам помог, поставьте галочку, если не сложно )

Answer (score 2):

Как написал @АнатолийШевелев, лучше всего в вашем случае будет создать еще один оберточные блок, где будет храниться стрелка и кнопка.

Пример.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#cssmenu li.has-sub>div >span').on('click', function() {
    $(this).removeAttr('href');
    var element = $(this).closest('li');
    console.log(element);
    if (element.hasClass('open')) {
      element.removeClass('open');
      element.find('li').removeClass('open');
      element.find('ul').hide();
    } else {
      element.addClass('open');
      element.children('ul').show();
      element.siblings('li').children('ul').hide();
      element.siblings('li').removeClass('open');
      element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('open');
      element.siblings('li').find('ul').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#cssmenu {
  width: 200px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#cssmenu ul ul {
  display: none;
}

.align-right {
  float: right;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li>div>a {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  border-left: 1px solid #1682ba;
  border-right: 1px solid #1682ba;
  border-top: 1px solid #1682ba;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  background: #36aae7;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  background: linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
}

#cssmenu>ul>li>a:hover,
#cssmenu>ul>li.active>a,
#cssmenu>ul>li.open>a {
  color: #eeeeee;
  background: #1fa0e4;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
  background: linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
}

#cssmenu>ul>li.open>a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1682ba;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li:last-child>a,
#cssmenu>ul>li.last>a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1682ba;
}

.holder {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.holder::after,
.holder::before {}

.holder::after {
  top: 17px;
  border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
  border-left: 2px solid #ffffff;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li>a:hover>span::after,
#cssmenu>ul>li.active>a>span::after,
#cssmenu>ul>li.open>a>span::after {
  border-color: #eeeeee;
}

.holder::before {
  top: 18px;
  border-top: 2px solid;
  border-left: 2px solid;
  border-top-color: inherit;
  border-left-color: inherit;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #32373e;
  border-left: 1px solid #32373e;
  border-right: 1px solid #32373e;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #eeeeee;
  background: #49505a;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

#cssmenu ul ul li:hover>a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.open>a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.active>a {
  background: #424852;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li:first-child>a {
  box-shadow: none;
}

#cssmenu ul ul ul li:first-child>a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

#cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li>ul>li:last-child>a,
#cssmenu>ul>li>ul>li.last>a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li>ul>li.open:last-child>a,
#cssmenu>ul>li>ul>li.last.open>a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #32373e;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li>ul>li.open:last-child>ul>li:last-child>a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub>a::after {}

#cssmenu ul ul li.active>a::after,
#cssmenu ul ul li.open>a::after,
#cssmenu ul ul li>a:hover::after {
  border-color: #ffffff;
}

.accordion-btn-wrap {
  width: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: 99999;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.accordion-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.item-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/js/all.js"></script>
<div id='cssmenu'>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="item-wrapper"><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></div>
    </li>
    <li class='active has-sub'>
      <div class="item-wrapper">
        <a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
        <span class="accordion-btn-wrap"><!-- Кнопка-->
                     <span class="accordion-btn">
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                     </span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <!-- Конец кнопки-->
      <ul>
        <li class='has-sub'>
          <div class="item-wrapper">
            <a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a>
            <span class="accordion-btn-wrap">
                      <span class="accordion-btn">
                         <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                      </span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <ul>
            <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
            <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
            <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="item-wrapper"><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></div>
    </li>
    <li class='last'>
      <div class="item-wrapper"><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

P.S. От себя могу добавить.

Старайтесь не писать `css`, который зависит от структуры вашего `html`.

Старайтесь не писать `js`, который зависит от структуры вашего `html`.

Не используйте `id` селекторы в `css` - это тоже не очень хорошо. Старайтесь везде использовать классы. Также посмотрите на [БЭМ](https://ru.bem.info/methodology/css/) - удобная вещь!